# Access Service Fabric cluster via .net standard with web api

Tags: service-fabric-stateless, azure-service-fabric, self-host-webapi

I have a service fabric stateless service which I am running inside my cluster within azure

At the moment the service in question only has 1 instance

I would like to be able to access data in the service via web api

How can I do this with .net standard not .net core?

There are a lot of links for creating web apis but they seem to be either Old or they refer to .net core

Some also give instructions for adding via visual studio which now doesn’t appear to be available within visual studio 2017

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net Core is only compatible with .Net Framework and .Net Core. Not .Net Standard unfortunately.

> ASP.NET Core is a new open-source and cross-platform framework for
>   building modern cloud based internet connected applications, such as
>   web apps, IoT apps and mobile backends. ASP.NET Core apps can run on
>   .NET Core or on the full .NET Framework. It was architected to provide
>   an optimized development framework for apps that are deployed to the
>   cloud or run on-premises. It consists of modular components with
>   minimal overhead, so you retain flexibility while constructing your
>   solutions. You can develop and run your ASP.NET Core apps
>   cross-platform on Windows, Mac and Linux. Learn more about ASP.NET
>   Core.

https://github.com/aspnet/Home

Comment: Thanks looks like I just need to create a new service which can connect to my existing .net standard ones